# Can I declare an instance variable in Java and use it in static initialization block?

Tags: java

```
class E implements Runnable {  
static Thread t1;  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
// some code  
}  
static {t1 = new Thread();}  
}
```

static init blocks execute when the class is first loaded. How will this static init block come to know that t1 is an already declared instance variable?

Comment: `t1` is static property not an instance one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No, you can't deal with instance variable inside static context,

**BONUS :)**

I am not sure why you need that, 
as `main()` is an entry method, you should not implement your logic there,

instead, create instance of `E` and call a method in `E` that will do your logic, don't declare all variables as `static` just to be able to use them from `main()`.

example:

```
public class E implements Runnable {  
    private Thread t1;

    public E(){
        t1 = new Thread();
    }

    public void doMyWork(){
        t1....
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        E e = new E();
        e.doMyWork();
    }  
}
```